# Nsight Visual studio 5.0 wont let me launch an app in the current environment

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gpu, nsight

I have to launch my Visual studio with a script that sets a bunch of environnment variables to look for DLLs, and other crucial variables to the application I'm normally trying to debug.  However, when I try to debug the same application in Visual Studio using Nsight, it won't let me launch the executable I'm trying to debug in the same environment that I launched my visual studio in, and I can't find anywhere that I can set any environment variables before I launch the application with Nsight.

Does anyone know how I can launch my application with the NSight GPU debugger in the current environment without having to set them on a user or system basis? Id like to avoid this route if possible. ALso im doing local host debugging if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to Nsight's project properties: Right click on your project -> Nsight user properties
2. Navigate to: Launch -> Launch action

   - Choose launch external program
   - Fill in a textbox with a path to your launcher script (it should launch the app in the end)
3. You might also want to check "Aplication is a launcher" checkbox

See also:

[NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition User Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/nsight/nsight_visual_studio_edition_user_guide.htm)

Comment: That only allows you to launch executables not scripts. I already tried that

Comment: Create a batch file in your working directory which sets the desired environment variables and starts your program. In the Nsight User Settings select "Launch external program" and enter "$(windir)\system32\cmd.exe". Check "Application is a launcher". In the command line arguments enter "/c <name_of_your_batch_file>.bat".